# Can I replace CheckPoint's SSL Network Extender (client) with some vanilla linux software?

Tags: linux, vpn, checkpoint, 64-bit

I used to run CheckPoint's SSL Network Extender to connect to a customer's network, but it looks like 64bit support for Linux is nowhere in sight. Could I use something else to connect, e.g. OpenVPN?

Comment: Do you mean "can I use eg OpenVPN to connect to a Checkpoint SSL Network Extender server" or "can I replace a Checkpoint SSL Network Extender-based solution with OpenVPN server and clients"?

Comment: Possibly, but I bet it's so proprietary that it won't work.

Comment: I completely echo Tom's sentiments above.

Comment: Can you even download the SSL Network Extender software any more? I've not been able to find it today.